# Create an executable file for Windows 8 using a code in java

Tags: java, io

How to make a Java application that can create an executable file for Windows 8 because I am developing an app that creates a exe file while installation.

```
public void load(String outoutfile,String mainclass,Object function){}
```

Comment: Yes, i tried to convert object into bytes and write it into file with magic number...

Comment: Please post the code you tried, and tell us what doesn't work, why, what is the expected behaviour, and what happened instead.

Answer (score 1):

Do not reinvent the wheel. There is already a tool that creates an executable package. See the documentation of Oracle: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html With this you can create native bundles (.exe on Windows) for different OS.
From the page mentioned:

```
javapackager -deploy -native -outdir packages -outfile BrickBreaker 
    -srcdir dist -srcfiles BrickBreaker.jar -appclass brickbreaker.Main 
    -name "BrickBreaker" -title "BrickBreaker demo"
```

The same can also be accomplished with an Ant task which might be easier to integrate. There is also the Maven plugin [javax-maven-plugin](https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin).

Comment: "Do not reinvent the wheel", it can be a good thing for him to learn how you can do it !

Comment: Not exeutable jar file its executable file (.exe) file

Comment: @JhonathanLdBaldivicio This one has the option to create a native bundle (.exe in the case of Windows)

Comment: `System.err.println("Let me Google that for you.");`